# The message that appears after casting a third vote in a moderator election contains a <br/>

Tags: bug, user-interface, election

After casting a third vote in the moderator election, this message appears.

[image]

The `<br/>` should either be fixed into a newline, or it should be removed altogether.

This was [originally reported on Pets.SE](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2290/9263), but comments said to raise it here.

Comment: Without the slash I think it should work fine.